# Choosing C struct name for doxygen?

Tags: c, struct, doxygen

How can I tell Doxygen to use the first declaration in this code:

```
typedef struct _decor_extents {
    int left;
    int right;
    int top;
    int bottom;
} decor_extents_t;
```

Cheers,
Kris

Answer (score 1):

Set `TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT = NO` in your Doxyfile.

This is actually the default behavior, so your existing Doxyfile must have been setting it to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want Doygen to use `struct _decor_extents`, rather than `decor_extents_t`?

If so, don't use a `typedef`. In other words, remove the `typedef` and the type name (`decor_extents_t`).

This does mean that any variable of this type will have to be declared as `struct _decor_extents`, rather than `decor_extents_t`.

Out of interest, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Furthermore, identifiers starting with `_` are by convention considered privates, so could be that removing the typedef doxygen will skip the whole type.

Comment: This for documenting the new 0.9 Compiz branch, which is basically 100% undocumented until this effor.t

Answer (score 0):

You could do either the aforementioned suggestion of reorganizing the struct:

```
typedef struct decor_extents_t { ... }
```

There is also a trick with doxygen itself for structs and classes to specify their name and start the documentation for them. See the manual [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/commands.html#cmdstruct).